# How to iterate Tab and its content based on data Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular8

I am getting below response from API.

```
const myObj = [
  {
    'tabName': 'Tab1',
    'otherDetails': [
      {
        'formType': 'Continuous'
      },
      {
        'formType': 'Batch',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'tabName': 'Tab2',
    'otherDetails': [         
      {
        'formType': 'Batch',
      }
    ]
  }    
];
```

In below function i am tabs and pushing formArray based form on api data, **Issue i am facing is in every tab both continuous and batch form are appearing multiple times.**

```
getMakeLineData() {  
var otherDetails = myObj.filter(m => m.otherDetails).map(m => m.otherDetails);
this.makeLineData = myObj;
if (otherDetails) {
  otherDetails.forEach(element => {       
    for (var i of element) {
      if (i.formType === 'Continuous') {           
         this.continuousType().push(this.createContinuousForm());
      } else if (i.formType === 'Batch')  {            
         this.batchType().push(this.createBatchForm());
      } 
    }
  });      
}
}
```

Can anyone help me prepare right logic.

Based on above response, From above data, i am iterating dynamic tabs and i want to push batch and Continuous form
which are related to that tab.

**Expected output -**

**In Tab1 -** Push Continuous and batch formarray both bcz in response of tab1 i have batch and Continuous form type in otherDetails key.

**In Tab2 -** Push batch formarray only bcz in response of Tab2 i have form type batch only in otherDetails key.

Below is my HTMl

```
<mat-tab-group class="lossMatGrpCls" mat-align-tabs="left">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let lineData of makeLineData">
        <mat-tab>
            <button class="validatorTabBgClr">{{lineData.tabName}}</button>

            <div *ngFor="let line of lineData.otherDetails">
                <form [formGroup]="dataCollectionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                    <!-- <--continuous Form start here -->
                    <div *ngIf="line && line.formType === 'Continuous'">
                        <div class="admin-console-main-wrapper" formArrayName="continuousType">
                            <div class="content-wrapper" *ngFor="let lineItem of continuousType().controls; let i=index"
                                [formGroupName]="i">
                                <h5 class="topbar-items-text">Design Process Capacity (Tonnes)</h5>
                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                    <input matInput type="text" class="line-fte-input smed-input"
                                        placeholder="Design Process Capacity" formControlName="designProcess">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <--continuous Form start here -->

                    <!-- <--Batch Form start here -->
                    <div *ngIf="line && line.formType === 'Batch'" class="admin-console-main-wrapper"
                        formArrayName="batchType">
                        <div class="content-wrapper" *ngFor="let lineBatchItem of batchType().controls; let i=index"
                            [formGroupName]="i">
                            <h5 class="topbar-items-text">Average BCT (mins)</h5>
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                <input matInput type="text" class="line-fte-input smed-input" placeholder="Average BCT"
                                    formControlName="avgBCT">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <--Batch Form ends here -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </mat-tab>
    </ng-container>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Don't create another look inside the method. Loop through your data directly in your template.

Comment: @VimalPatel, If i dont iterate the loop then how i can execute push method in template

Comment: You dont need that method at all. You already have all the info in your main object.

Comment: @VimalPatel, i am not getting which method you are talking to remove? Can you plz help me to edit my code.. i am not able to achieve my expected output thats why i am here to ask you..plz help on the code

Comment: @VimalPatel, if you are talking to remove component method, than how i will push the form array based on api response data?

Comment: @VimalPatel, if i remove the below code , for (var i of element) {
      if (i.formType === 'Continuous') {           
         this.continuousType().push(this.createContinuousForm());
      } else if (i.formType === 'Batch')  {            
         this.batchType().push(this.createBatchForm());
      } 
    } then how my push work in template?

Comment: May I know what goes under "this.createContinuousForm(): method?

Comment: @TinkuTiwari, not repeat questions. If you check your profile (click at top-rigth, where you has your "avatar") you can see your history questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template-driven forms instead of reactive forms. For this, you only need to define the form-field property in your array of objects.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{ tab.tabName }}</ng-template>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let line of tab.otherDetails">
      <form>
        <div *ngIf="line && line.formType === 'Continuous'">
          <h5 class="topbar-items-text">Design Process Capacity (Tonnes)</h5>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input
              matInput
              type="text"
              [(ngModel)]="line.value"
              name="value"
              placeholder="Design Process Capacity"
            />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="line && line.formType === 'Batch'">
          <h5 class="topbar-items-text">Average BCT (mins)</h5>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <input
              matInput
              type="text"
              [(ngModel)]="line.value"
              name="value"
              placeholder="Average BCT"
            />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </form>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Demo:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t1infl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I need this with reactive form only.. In this.createContinuousform() contain below code..
createContinuousForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      designProcess: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
  createBatchForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      avgBCT: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

Comment: What is the problem with using template forms?

Comment: Actually this was the requirement, and we are pushing formarray on every push. For ex - Based on json response i am pushing formarray continuos and Batch , and every form Array will create multiple submit button based on form array and form group.